# DocuSign Rest API C# Proxy

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm testing DocuSign integration and I've managed to work out most of the API, but I have one issue I can't resolve.

DESCRIPTION:
- Two documents are added to an envelope
- Each document has one recipient with a SignHere tab for each.

PROBLEM:
When I send the envelope, both recipients see BOTH documents, but I need each recipient to see only the document they have to sign.

STEPS TAKEN:
I read in DS documentation that you need to set the following, which I've done:
**eDef.EnforceSignerVisibility = "true";**

I also read that you need to enable "Document Visibility" on the account. But when I look at my account properties on the DS site, there is no "Document Visibility" option displayed anywhere.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Document Visibility feature is enabled by default on developer sandbox accounts for testing so you should be able to access it.  The feature can be found in the **Admin** section under **Sending Settings** as seen below.

Can you confirm if you're seeing this option?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ergin. Thanks for your input. I was signing in using the wrong URL and account. I needed to sign in to the demo account, which has a different url.

Comment: Ok cool, in that case can you accept the answer so others can easily find? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you need to call DocuSign support team and ask them to enable that option for you in your account.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfYwE.png)

Then, it will be available for your account in admin side.
I hope this help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i already raised a support issue with DS and got the following reply:

Comment: DS REPLY: I am sorry for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I'm unable to assist you with this as this is no longer within our scope as a Tier 1 Support. For these situations we usually direct users to a few free sources of support we have available. 

You can post on our very active Stack Overflow board for help as well as our own Community where you may find someone who has had your exact situation and resolved it. 

Stack Overflow may be accessed here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing. After contacting support I discovered there are two different ways to sign in to DocuSign, and they use different URL's and have different account numbers.

I was signing in using the standard free account, which apparently has a limited subset of properties available. Once I signed in to the "demo" account, I could see all properties including "Document Visibility."

https://account.docusign.com/#/username

https://account-d.docusign.com/#/username

The first URL is for using a standard account (free or live paid account). The second URL is for signing in using the demo account.

Both accounts have the same email address and password.